# MVC request validation is off, still throws exception when accessing Request.Form

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

By default ASP.net will do request validation to make sure values submitted by the user aren't potentially dangerous.  See [this popular queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client?rq=1) regarding how to disable it.

I have disabled it successfully so that the controller doesn't throw an exception if potentially dangerous characters are detected.  However, if I access the Request.Forms property, it attempts to do request validation again and will throw the exception.  Specifically what I'm doing is this: `request.Form.ToString()`.

The controller has been decorated with `[ValidateInput(false)]` and the Model decorated with `[AllowHtml()]` neither of which are being honored while accessing the `Request.Forms` property.  How can I do this without the exception being thrown?

Comment: did you add `requestValidationMode="2.0"` to the `httpRuntime` element in your web.config? http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147

Comment: That was is.  Wish I would have tried it before asking the question -- if you submit this as the answer I will mark it accordingly.

Comment: Net 4.5 provides the [`Request.Unvalidated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx) property which provides request values without validation. E.g.: `request.Unvalidated.Form.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net 4.0 adds additional request validation that you need to disable by adding `requestValidationMode="2.0"` to the `httpRuntime` element of your web.config.

See [ASP.NET breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147) for more info.